# What does the error code "ERR.RAF.APPLICATION" mean when requesting SeatMap information from Sabre?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, sabre

I had code that was working without issue until the the 4th, now this is the only response I get when I try and test my application with the SeatMap endpoint, https://api.test.sabre.com/v3.0.0/book/flights/seatmaps?mode=seatmap

```
{  
   "status":"Unknown",
   "type":"Application",
   "errorCode":"ERR.RAF.APPLICATION",
   "timeStamp":"2016-01-08T12:42:59+00:00",
   "message":"{
       \"EnhancedSeatMapRS\":{
           \"ApplicationResults\":{
                \"status\":\"NotProcessed\",\"Error\":   [{
                        \"type\":\"Application\",\"timeStamp\":\"2016-01-08T06:42:59.623-    06:00\",\"SystemSpecificResults\":[{\"timeStamp\":\"2016-01-08T06:42:59.623-06:00\",\"Message\":

   [{\"code\":\"700001\",\"content\":\"Internal service     error\"}]}]}]}},\"Links\": 
    [{\"rel\":\"self\",\"href\":\"https://api.test.sabre.com/v3.0.0/book/flight    s/seatmaps?mode=seatmaps\"},    {\"rel\":\"linkTemplate\",\"href\":\"https://api.test.sabre.com/<version>/b    ook/flights/seatmaps?mode=<mode>\"}]}"
}
```

I have not been able to find any information from Sabre on this error code. Has anyone else seen this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can that be related to the mode=seatmap url parameter?

Based on the documentation, the accepted value seems to be plural:
mode=seatmap**s**

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/seat_map

You can always use the API explorer to test service parameters using your credentials:

https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs

Comment: No, I'll post the code in a little bit that I'm using to call, but it is copied exactly from their documentation, and it was working until a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

This may be tied to an issue from the TEST/Sandbox environment you are hitting. Recommend testing again to see if the issue persist or sharing the request you are sending over.